# Remap standard motions

Tags: cursor-motions, object-motions, key-bindings

I have a file formatted like this

```
+---------------------------------+
| Text text text                  |
| Text text text                  |
| Text text text                  |
+---------------------------------+
```

Within the ASCII box I would like to remap the standard VIM keys, like <kbd>$</kbd>, <kbd>_</kbd>, ... to ignore the ASCII box during editing.

For example, <kbd>$</kbd> should place the cursor on the last letter of the text and not on the '|'. I can make it with the simple

```
nnoremap <buffer> $ f\|ge
```

This works great, but when I try to combine the new <kbd>$</kbd> with other VIM commands, this doesn't work any more. For example, <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> deletes the entire like including the last '|' char.

In my understanding, I have to use `onoremap` somehow to support motions, and then `vnoremap` to support visual mode.

My question is:

- How should I remap <kbd>$</kbd> so that it nicely integrates with all VIM-aspects? (visual mode, motions, objects, ...)

Comment: Bad idea, really bad idea. Please don't go that route. Rather, please reconsider whether such high-ceremony formatting is really needed.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Yes, actually you are right. This is just an exercise. So, please, don't judge the task itself. But this is definitely doable with vim, right?

Comment: You're going to want to look into `onoremap`. You are in operator pending mode when, for instance, you press `d` and vim is waiting for a motion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you start with this normal mode mapping:

```
nnoremap <buffer> $ f\|ge
```

The visual-mode mapping is identical:

```
vnoremap <buffer> $ f\|ge
```

Then, for *operator-pending mode* (like after `d`, `y`, and so on), you need a different kind of mapping. `:help omap-info` tells us:

> To ignore the starting cursor position and select different text, you can have
>   the omap start Visual mode to select the text to be operated upon.

Apparently, you need to use `:normal` to trigger the selection:

```
onoremap <buffer> $ :<C-u>normal! vf\|ge<CR>
```

However, we could avoid the duplication of the motion, and delegate to the already defined visual mode mapping (note how `:normal!` changed to `:normal` to invoke mappings):

```
onoremap <buffer> $ :<C-u>normal v$<CR>
```

#### Caveat

To implement this consistently for all built-in motions will be quite a challenge. I would not recommend to actually use something like that. Best to get rid of such high-ceremony formatting. If that's not possible, I'd rather temporarily copy the text into a scratch buffer, do the modifications (without borders) there, and then paste back.